# The app works on the emulator but not the actual phone

Tags: android-studio

I'm working on a project using android studio and kotlin. I run the app (to test it) sometimes on the emulator and sometimes on my phone(Samsung s8).

I haven't started actual coding yet, all what I have done is some XML coding and the following code in kotlin to move from activity to another:

```
val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, AnotherActivity::class.java)
startActivity(i)
```

everything was fine actually until few days later the app crushes after I click the button that moves me to the next activity. I looked for errors but there were none. so I tried it on the emulator and it works!!! since then the app NEVER worked on my phone -I tried 3 different phones-.

I searched the internet and some people suggested that I might have an SDK or JDK issues, my JDK is updated and I have all the necessary  SDK files installed.

also I've seen that it could be the fast that I'm not supporting the phone API(the API is 24) my minimum API support is 18 as my Gradle.build file shows bellow

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.niuxu.shift18"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
```

so I hope that someone could tell me what is wrong with it and why it crushes every time I click the button that takes me to the next activity while it works fine on the emulator...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, try to run the app on the device after updating Intel® HAXM driver.

Comment: its updated. but do I need to keep it updated though if I'm trying to run it on my phone?